# .Net Framework 4.0 - Opcodes.Box present in Dictionary with int key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, garbage, xbox360

I'm trying to investigate whether dictionaries with enum keys still generate garbage in newer versions of .Net (say >= 4)

See Shawn Hargreaves blog post here for details on why I'm even fretting about this...
(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana.aspx)
Very specific I know but garbage on the xbox is / can be a very really problem.

I created a little .Net v4 console application comparing the IL generated for Dictionary and Dicationary and noticed a 'box' opcode in both sets of code which really confused me.

```
.method private hidebysig 
    instance int32 FindEntry (
        !TKey key
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x61030
    // Code size 138 (0x8a)
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] int32,
        [1] int32
    )

    IL_0000: ldarg.1
    IL_0001: box !TKey   <----Hmmmm!
    IL_0006: brtrue.s IL_000e

    IL_0008: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0009: call void System.ThrowHelper::ThrowArgumentNullException(valuetype System.ExceptionArgument)

    IL_000e: ldarg.0
    IL_000f: ldfld int32[] class System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<!TKey, !TValue>::buckets
    IL_0014: brfalse.s IL_0088
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.box%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Convert a value type (of the type specified in valTypeToken) to a true
>   object reference.

Is the box here not a heap allocation? If not, then how can I tell when there's heap allocations that might cause the Xbox to struggle?(from looking at the IL) Does it depend on some other context?
Would a memory profiler (CLR Profiler for example) be the only way to tell for sure?

Comment: The link you posted has (in one of its comments) another link: http://beardseye.blogspot.it/2007/08/nuts-enum-conundrum.html that talks about the enum boxing problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is a box, but no it shouldn't matter in this case - at least, not for *regular* .NET; this is a `!= null` check; the JIT knows how to recognise these for value-types, and can **remove** that check from the machine code.

Allegedly.

To tell for sure, you'd need to look at the post-JIT machine code, not the IL.

It will also matter which JIT you are using, which makes it harder.

Worst case: you could use the CoreCLR code to roll your own value-type dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

I will say that problem was solved. I took the code from http://beardseye.blogspot.it/2007/08/nuts-enum-conundrum.html

```
enum TestEnum
{
    e10,
    e9,
    e8,
    e7,
    e6,
    e5,
    e4,
    e3,
    e2,
    e1
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<TestEnum, int> dict = new Dictionary<TestEnum, int>();

        for (int l = 0; l < 100000; l++)
        {
            TestEnum x = (TestEnum)(l % 10);
            dict[x] = 100000 - (int)x;
        }

        for (TestEnum x = TestEnum.e10; x <= TestEnum.e1; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dict[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

And I've run it with the profiler of Visual Studio 2013. There are no allocations of the `TestEnum` "object". Note that if I change the code to

```
dict[x] = 100000 - x.GetHashCode();
```

then I get many allocations of `TestEnum`.

Other test:

```
public class TestEnumComparer : IEqualityComparer<TestEnum>
{

    public bool Equals(TestEnum x, TestEnum y)
    {
        return x == y;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TestEnum obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and

```
Dictionary<TestEnum, int> dict = new Dictionary<TestEnum, int>(new TestEnumComparer());
```

Still I get many allocations of `TestEnum`.

So I'll say that `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` does something to not box enums.

If you look in the [EqualityComparer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs.html) source, in the `CreateComparer()` method:

```
// If T is an int-based Enum, return an EnumEqualityComparer<T>
// See the METHOD__JIT_HELPERS__UNSAFE_ENUM_CAST and METHOD__JIT_HELPERS__UNSAFE_ENUM_CAST_LONG cases in getILIntrinsicImplementation
if (t.IsEnum && Enum.GetUnderlyingType(t) == typeof(int))
{
    return (EqualityComparer<T>)RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter((RuntimeType)typeof(EnumEqualityComparer<int>), t);
}
```

there is some special code to compare `int` `enum` and only them.

And I can confirm that if I change the `enum` to

```
enum TestEnum : long
```

then the allocations caused by the boxing appear! :-)

So, in the end

```
Dictionary<enum_that_is_an_int, Foo>
```

is **safe** to use,

every other type of `enum` isn't! :-)

Note that this is true for .NET >= 4.0 . I've looked at the `CreateComparer()` of *mscorlib 2.0.0.0* and there isn't a check like this, so on .NET 2.0-3.5 the `Dictionary<enum_that_is_an_int, Foo>` isn't safe to use.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know - thanks - at least for the desktop CLR anyway - the CF on the Xbox could be doing something different I guess (as could Mono) - checking with a memory profiler seems like the only way to know for sure.

Comment: @PaulCunningham Or you can live happy with a little paranoia and implement an `IEqualityComparer<>` that does cast.

Comment: In the meantime, this good ol' boxing issue is gone for all possible underlying types: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/455f59f089ff2e96375e800c9b7866446f16cb30/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs#L67-L87